# Getting django.http.request when print for loop content

Tags: django, beautifulsoup

In django, I am trying to view google search result (2) for a keyword by using beautifulsoup. but when enter keyword I am getting result as

"Source code for django.http.request
[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/http/request/"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/http/request/%22)

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests # ️ Requests module
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # ️ BeautifulSoup module
from django.http import HttpResponse

def search(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={request}"
        headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
        }

        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

        results = []
        search_results = soup.select("div.g")
        for result in search_results[:2]:  # Limiting to the first 2 results
            title = result.select_one("h3").get_text()
            #description = result.select_one("div.IsZvec").get_text()
            link = result.select_one("a").get("href")
        results.append({"title": title,  "link": link})

        return render(request, "result.html", {"results":results})

    return render(request, "result.html")
```

Here is the template I am using as html template
HTML Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Django FBV With Beautifulsoup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <style>
    p {
      font-size: 20px
    }

    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="mt-5 mb-5">Get Title From Any Website</h1>
      
      <!-- Form -->
      <form method="POST" action="{% url 'results' %}"> {% csrf_token %} <div class="mt-4">
          
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter keyword" rows="5" required="required">
            </textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Go</button>

      </form>

      <!-- Result -->
      {% for a in results %}
      <br/><br/>
      {{ a.title}}<br/>
      {{ a.link}}<br/>
      {% endfor %}

      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you really want to have Google search results, make your life easier and use the API. Google is notoriously difficult to scrape, yet a lot of beginners think it's just a perfect site to start with. It's not. They randomize the class names, make parts of the site dyniamic (bs4 is just an HTML parser) etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={request}"
```

This is wrong.

it should be

```
url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={request.POST.get('keyword')}"
```